# Why does the input to xargs is 1 string but without is strings in separate line?

Tags: bash, sed, xargs, echo

I am trying to pipe file to rm via xargs. I understand that what I am tryng to do could be done by git clean but I am practicing the cli.
I tried this:

```
for files in $(git status --porcelain| sed 's/^??//g'); do echo $files; done | xargs rm -rf
```

but it did not work. I figured it was because when running this:

```
for files in $(git status --porcelain| sed 's/^??//g'); do echo $files; done | xargs
```

The files seem to be in 1 string separated by a space.
But when I run `for files in $(git status --porcelain| sed 's/^??//g'); do echo -n $files; done` the files are displayed in the console in a separate line.

So (if I am right on this) what is the difference between:
`for files in $(git status --porcelain| sed 's/^??//g'); do echo -n $files; done | xargs`
and

`for files in $(git status --porcelain| sed 's/^??//g'); do echo -n $files; done`

and the files in the second case are displayed each in each own line and in the first case it is one string?  And how would I fix this so that it works with rm -rf?

Comment: The files are indeed on separate lines. It's just that you're collecting them back onto a single line by piping them into `xargs`. Try `xargs -n1` which will force it to only process a single argument at a time to prove this to yourself.

Comment: @Celada:Now I get the files with no space as 1 string

Comment: You have not use `xargs` at all: just to replace `echo` by `rm`

Comment: @Celada:Hm. I was using echo -n when trying to figure this out. You are right when I do the same command with -n1 I get the files at a separate line, but rm does not do anything

Comment: As said above, you are not using `xargs` correctly. This should do what you are trying to do if the rest of your syntax is right. `git status --porcelain | sed 's/^??//g' | xargs rm -rf`

Comment: Xargs reads the stdin stream, but if you are echoing in a for-loop, the stdin stream I believe would be the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: check `git clean --help` instead of manually removing stuff with `xargs` and `rm -rf`. You will eventually get hurt by whitespaces if you use `xargs`

Answer (score 1):

You are making your life more complicated than necessary ;-)

If the subshell command (the expression inside your `$()`) already provides a list of filenames, and the "target command" (rm -rf in your case) already accepts a list of filenames, why not just use

```
git status --porcelain| sed 's/^??//g' | xargs rm -rf
```

Or, if you wish to practice a "for loop" in bash, you don't need xargs:

```
for f in $(git status --porcelain| sed 's/^??//g') ; do
    rm -rf $f
done
```

BTW... doubly check your 'rm -rf' commands (adding an 'echo' before 'rm -rf') before executing them, silly errors happen and you'll regret it!!